# Seed rails production with same development seedfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to seed my production database on Heroku with the seeds in `db/seeds.rb` with a command like `rake db:seed`.

The only answers I have found related to this seem to say I can only seed production database with another gem like seedbank.

Isn't there a way with vanilla rails to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can run in your shell

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

It will seed your db with `db/seeds.rb` file the same way as in development on your local machine

Comment: Wow how did I not try this. Thanks for the quick response.